# BufferedReader UTF-8 BOM

Tags: php, encoding, byte-order-mark

I have a method in Java where I try to get one integer (user id) through a POST json request, this is the method:

```
public static Integer getUserIdOwnerOfMsg(Message msg) {
        Integer idUser = null;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("textMsg", msg.getTextMsg());
            jsonObject.put("hourMsg", msg.getHourMsg());

            List list = new LinkedList();
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(jsonObject));
            String jsonString = list.toString();

            String urlStr = SERVER_PATH + "getUserIdOwnerOfMsgJSON.php";
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "your user agent");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "sp,SP;q=0.5");
            //con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");

            String urlParameters = "json=" + jsonString;

            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            InputStream instream;

            int status = con.getResponseCode();

            if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                instream = con.getErrorStream();
            else
                instream = con.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, "UTF-8")); // ISO-8859-1
            in.mark(1);
            if(in.read() != 0xFEFF)
                in.reset();
            String inputLine;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                response.append(inputLine);

            in.close();

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            Boolean correct = object.getBoolean("correct");
            if (correct) {
                idUser = object.getInt("id");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  idUser;
    }
```

The problem is that the response contains a UTF-8 BOM character, on postman the result it's ok and I can see the id: (`{"id":"7","correct":true}`)

[image: Postman]

But debugging on android studio I got the value `""` or `null` for `idUser`, I don't know why, I've tried so many ways to resolve this problem without succeed.

Also on the `php` server side I've executed `echo mb_detect_encoding($idUsuario);` and I got `ASCII` encoding in case that could help to find the solution.

Any help will be apreciated, thank you!

Comment: UTF8 does not ever need a BOM, and PHP does not care about encodings. Chances are your text editor is adding it to one or more of your PHP source files before the opening `<?php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I got the solution, I post it here in case someone have the same issue as me, the problem was with the parameters of the JSON, because they included `UTF-8` characters like `€`, so instead of reading the parameters like this:

```
wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
```

I have to do this:

```
byte[] buf = urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8");
wr.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
```

I post also the complete function in case someone needs it:

```
public static Integer getUserIdOwnerOfMsg(Message msg) {
    Integer idUser = null;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("textMsg", msg.getTextMsg());
        jsonObject.put("hourMsg", msg.getHourMsg());

        List list = new LinkedList();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(jsonObject));
        String jsonString = list.toString();

        String urlStr = SERVER_PATH + "getUserIdOwnerOfMsgJSON.php";
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "your user agent");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "sp,SP;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "json=" + jsonString;

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (con.getOutputStream());
        byte[] buf = urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8");
        wr.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        InputStream instream;

        int status = con.getResponseCode();

        if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            instream = con.getErrorStream();
        else
            instream = con.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")),8192);
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            response.append(inputLine);

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        Boolean correct = object.getBoolean("correct");
        if (correct) {
            try {
                String idUserText = object.getString("id");
                idUser = Integer.valueOf(idUserText);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        in.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  idUser;
}
```

That's all, happy coding!